# Promtail and Grafana - json log file from docker container not displayed

Tags: docker, logging, docker-compose, grafana, grafana-loki

my application's services are deployed via docker-compose. Currently, I also deployed Grafana, Loki and Promtail within the same docker-compose network.

Following the getting-started guide, collecting and displaying the log files from `/var/log` with the config

```
- job_name: system
entry_parser: raw
static_configs:
- targets:
    - localhost
  labels:
    job: varlogs
    __path__: /var/log/*log
```

works fine.

However, my backend logs (NestJS) into a log file which is stored in a docker volume.
Example log entry:

```
{"message":"Mapped {/api/drink, POST} route","context":"RouterExplorer","level":"info","timestamp":"2021-03-23T17:08:16.334Z"}
```

The path to the log is

```
/var/lib/docker/volumes/my_volume/_data/general.log
```

When I add the following config to Promtail

```
 - job_name: backend
pipeline_stages:
- json:
    expressions:
      level: level
      message: message
      timestamp: timestamp
      context: context
static_configs:
- targets:
    - localhost
  labels:
    job: backend
    __path__: /var/lib/docker/volumes/my_volume/_data/general.log
```

and use the query `{job="backend"}` in Grafana, **nothing is displayed**.
Furthermore, the log of the promtail container doesn't give any information.

What am I missing?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I guess there is a verb missing in the header

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your pipeline stages you need to store the extracted values:

```
pipeline_stages:
- json:
    expressions:
      level: level
      message: message
      timestamp: timestamp
      context: context
- timestamp:
    source: timestamp
- labels:
    level:
    context:
- output:
    source: message
```

This will set the timestamp, the labels `context`, `level` and the `message` will be the log line.

Documentation can be found [here](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/clients/promtail/stages/).

Comment: the timestamp, labels and output keys are missing ":". Spent a good half an hour figuring out why my YAML is invalid.

Comment: Sorry for that, its now fixed. Though better then one being invalid by wrong whitespaces :)